# Delete Record from Acumatica by REST API EndPoint

Tags: acumatica

I am using acumatica and trying to delete record by the  REST API EndPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do it like the following (using Sales Order as an example)

DELETE : {{BaseUrl}}/entity/{{EndpointName}}/{{EndpointVersion}}/SalesOrder/{{SalesOrderType}}/{{SalesOrderNbr}}

DELETE : {{BaseUrl}}/entity/{{EndpointName}}/{{EndpointVersion}}/SalesOrder/{{id}}

Remove a Record by Key Fields:

https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d806636f-3cb8-4fd6-bc1e-fef9cdf9683d
Remove a Record by ID

https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=04825ddc-c3af-49de-8663-ae119e84b987